# Algorithm to generate all N-size variations of natural numbers

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, number-theory

For a size N>=1 (an input variable) I need an algorithm to generate all variations (no duplicates allowed) of natural numbers greater than zero.

For N=1, this is trivial:

```
[1], [2], [3], ...
```

For N=2, I think of having rounds with an increasing limit L where the first element starts from 1 to L and the second element is L when the first element not equals L or goes from 1 to to L+1 otherwise:

```
L = 1
  [1,2], 
L = 2
  [1,3], [2,1], [2,3], 
L = 3
  [1,4], [2,4], [3,1], [3,2], [3,4],
L = 4
  [1,5], [2,5], [3,5], [4,1], [4,2], [4,3], [4,5],
L = 5
  ...
```

Is it possible to scale this algorithm to any N>2? Like for N=3:

```
[1,2,3], [?,?,?], ...?
```

Or is there a better algorithm to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: When do you terminate the algorithm?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami theoretically can run indefinitely

Comment: Just simply use nested for loops of depth $N$ and add a condition that the values to be not equal. It is trivial.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Sorry, I cannot see how to do it for N>2 as an input parameter. Could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first observation, if you can do it for $N=2$, then you can do it for any $N$ using the same process.

Think of the case $N=2$ as "diagonalising" two copies of the infinite list for $N=1$ by just dropping duplicates. Then you can do $N=3$ by "diagonalising" a copy of $N=2$ with a copy of $N=1$. The details are left as an exercise.

However, there's also a way to enumerate all of the sets that lets you do random access.

I'm going to use the natural numbers $\mathbb{N} = \left\{ 0, 1, \ldots \right\}$ because the maths works out better, but all you need to do is add one to every element to solve your problem.

Suppose you have a set of natural numbers $X$ with cardinality $N$. Let $x_1, x_2, \cdots x_N$ be the integers in increasing order. Then the index of this set in the lexicographic ordering of *all* sets with this property is:

$$i_N(X) = \sum_{1 \le i \le N} { x_i \choose i }$$

For example, suppose that $N=3$. Then:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
i_3\left(\left\{0, 1, 2\right\}\right) & = & { 2 \choose 3 } + { 1 \choose 2 } + {0 \choose 1 } = 0\\
i_3\left(\left\{0, 1, 3\right\}\right) & = & { 3 \choose 3 } + { 1 \choose 2 } + {0 \choose 1 } = 1\\
i_3\left(\left\{0, 2, 3\right\}\right) & = & { 3 \choose 3 } + { 2 \choose 2 } + {0 \choose 1 } = 2\\
i_3\left(\left\{1, 2, 3\right\}\right) & = & { 3 \choose 3 } + { 2 \choose 2 } + {1 \choose 1 } = 3\\
i_3\left(\left\{0, 1, 4\right\}\right) & = & { 4 \choose 3 } + { 1 \choose 2 } + {0 \choose 1 } = 4
\end{eqnarray*}$$

...and so on. If you represent the set as a bit vector, this is known as enumerative coding.

At any rate, this index function can be inverted in a reasonably straightforward way.

Let's suppose you want to find $i_4^{-1}(85)$. The first step is to find the largest $x$ such that ${x \choose 4 } \le 85$. We find that

$${ 8 \choose 4 } \le 85 < { 9 \choose 4 }$$

so the highest value in the set is going to be $8$. Then:

$$i_4^{-1}(85) = \left\{ 8 \right\} \cup i_3^{-1}\left(85 - {8 \choose 4}\right)$$

Using the base case:

$$i_0^{-1}(0) = \emptyset$$

We get:

$$i_4^{-1}(85) = \left\{ 8, 5, 3, 2 \right\}$$

For more details, see:

- Cover, T., *Enumerative Source Encoding*. IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, Vol IT-19, No 1, Jan 1973.